# Store array values in a text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on python 2.7
.
I am getting serial data from UART.

I am trying to save serial data values along with the real time when the data is received.

Data received from UART is of the form :

2.1862745098X 2.42156862745X 2.42156862745X 0.401960784314X 0.0X 0.637254901961X 1.49019607843X ............so on and so forth

I am saving the values along with time using the below code:

```
f1 = open('accelerometer sensor1.txt','w')
while 1:
 # Read from serial port, blocking
 data =ser.read(1)
 data1=(data)
 
        
 # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
 n = ser.inWaiting()
 data1 = (data1 + ser.read(n))
 l = data1.split( )
 
 #t1 = datetime.datetime.now()


 
 x = [d.strip("X") for d in l if d[len(d)-1] == "X"]
 for i in range(0,len(x)):
     f1.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
     f1.write("\t")
     f1.write(str(x[i]))
     f1.write("\n")
```

Problem I am facing is I am receiving large number of values at a particular time. So when I save the data , it is of the form:

```
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.1862745098
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.42156862745
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.71568627451
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.401960784314
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.0
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.637254901961
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.49019607843
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.42156862745
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.5
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.58823529412
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.78431372549
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.0
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.196078431373
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.17647058824
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.74509803922
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.49019607843
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.44117647059
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.33333333333
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.558823529412
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.0
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  0.205882352941
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  1.43137254902
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.08823529412
```

I do not want in this format,I want the real time for each sample received rather that real time for a group of sample points received.

I want text file to show something like this:

```
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980000  2.1862745098
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980010  2.42156862745
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980020  1.71568627451
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980030  0.401960784314
2014-09-22 11:30:40.980040  0.0
```

How can I do so? Please give some suggestions.

Thanks`

**EDIT**

I want each sample point to have different timestamp. This should be possible because each sample point is coming through serial port individually and not in a group. I think there may be a problem in how I read these sample point, if I could somehow read them individually then my purpose would be solved.

I tried getting each sample point individually. I am able to do so but the code has become very slow.
I just did

```
data =ser.readline(5)
     data1=(data)
```

Values coming through UART are of type:
127X 154X 100X 158X 0X 20X .............

Is there a way to read the values individually and also without compromising the speed.

Comment: Do you know your desired format? If so, please add it. If not, please describe more your need. It seem that you don't need to have historical data, correct?

Comment: please check the question again. I have added desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to have the average of the numbers within a timestamp. Please have a look at this code, it aggregates the given value and - if the timestamp differs - writes it to file.

The cache variable should be initialized outside the loop ;-)

```
cache = ('', 0, 0.0)

def aggregate(value):
    now = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    c_date, c_count, c_avg = cache
    if now != c_date:
        # write c_avg and c_date to file
        f1.write(c_date)
        f1.write("\t")
        f1.write(str(c_avg))
        f1.write("\n")

        # after that, clear c_count and c_avg
        c_count = 0
        c_avg = 0.0

    if c_count is 0:
        c_count = 1
        c_avg = float(value)
    else:
        c_avg = ((c_avg * c_count) + float(value)) / (c_count + 1)
        c_count += 1

    cache = (now, c_count, c_avg)


for i in range(0,len(x)):
    aggregate(x[i])
```

I hope this fill your need.

Cheers

Comment: This answer does not fulfills my need. I do not want to take an average of sample points. I want each sample point to have different timestamp without taking their average. This should be possible because each sample point is coming through serial port individually and not in a group. I think there may be a problem in how I read these sample point, if I could somehow read them individually then my purpose would be solved but for now I am not able to do that.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Can't you tell this before? I don't have any clue about your environment. It's not my job, i just tried to help. Try it on your own, I am out.